# Visual basic "Finally on exception"

Tags: vb.net

I want to run a block of code after the catch statements regardless of which exception happens but only when some exception happens. So basically it's a finally statement that requires an exception in order to execute. Is there an easy way to do this in visual basic?

Comment: Well, what is it?  Regardless of any exception of only on some exception?  You can't have it both.

Comment: Your first sentence requests simultaneous existence of two mutually-exclusive conditions. If you give some pseudo-code you could avoid a down-vote. Sometimes you just have to write all the code even though it seems onerous.

Comment: The code would be what Joe Enos posted but without the boolean. I don't think it exists in visual basic though.

Comment: What's the point of this? Why don't you just put the code inside of the `Catch` block? That's what it's for!

Comment: @CodyGray I love when some random know it all douche bag does not understand so they down vote me... Maybe you should consider that you don't know everything before you go and down vote someone?

Comment: Maybe you should consider that someone leaving a comment asking a question has nothing to do with whether they downvoted your question. You have absolutely no reason to believe that I was the person who downvoted, you're just making an assumption. And a bad one at that. Talk about being a douche bag and thinking you know everything!

Comment: Also, rather than calling people names who are trying to help you, consider improving the question. If I didn't understand it, there are probably others who don't either. That is, assuming I'm not a complete idiot.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Dim isException As Boolean = False
Try
    ....
Catch ex As ApplicationException
    isException = True
    ....
Catch ex As Exception
    isException = True
    ....
Finally
    If (isException)
        ....
    End If
End Try
```

Comment: Not really worth it. Only slightly less code but also slightly harder to read.

Comment: I like this version better - when you're looking at the code in 2 years, it'll be obvious what this does, but with the other version you'll be scratching your head about the nested try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like it, but how about a nested `Try`:

```
Try
    Try
        ....
    Catch ex As ApplicationException
        Throw
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
Catch
    ' This is your "finally"
End Try
```

Comment: Not what I was hoping for but it will do.

Comment: Actually, having to throw another exception is not at all attractive. Still props for the effort though.

Comment: You're not actually throwing another exception, just re-throwing the exception you already have, so you keep your stack-trace and everything. But I agree, not the most elegant-looking code.

Answer (score 0):

The finally block of the If statement will always be called regardless if there is an exception raised or not. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/fk6t46tz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

The only other way to do this is to have another method that accepts an exception as a parameter and call that method from the exception catch.

Comment: Lame... I wanted this so there would be less code but the solution you gave would make more code. Oh well...

Comment: Lame or not its the specification of the Try...Catch...Finally block

Answer (score 0):

You could add different exception blocks, like this:

```
Try
    ' do operation
' Most specific:
Catch e As ApplicationException
    ' do something only if ApplicationException has occurred
' Least specific:
Catch e As Exception
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Second exception caught.", e);
End Try
```

Comment: If ApplicationException happens then Exception won't execute.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but isn't that what you're after? You want to execute a different piece of code in case a certain exception occurs. If there's code you need to execute for every exception you can extract it to a method and reuse the method. The finally keyword is really not what you're after. This is exactly what finally is not meant for. Finally is there to execute always, exception or not.